# What to do about syslog timestamp anomaly?

Tags: bug-reporting, logging, syslog

I was just looking through my `syslog` when I spotted this:

```
Jul  7 21:13:34 <Computer-Name> kernel: [14361.093581] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Jul  7 21:09:27 <Computer-Name> thermald[843]: sysfs write failed /no_turbo
Jul  7 21:14:03 <Computer-Name> NetworkManager[1095]: <info>  [1467922443.6944] device (enp3s0): link disconnected (deferring action for 4 seconds)
```

As you will see, there is an anomaly with the second entry. Is this something to worry about? What could this have been caused by? And is there anything I should do about this (e.g. is there somewhere where I should report this?)?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparent log file time stamp anomalies do occur, albeit rarely. The time stamp portion of the log entry is from when the related operation was initiated, yet the actual line is written to the log, if required, when the operation completes, or times out or whatever.

For your example I assume it took several minutes for the thermald sysfs write to timeout, and meanwhile the CPU1 message had already been entered in the log.

Here is an example from one of my server computers, where the file bot_trap.html takes about 50 minutes to deliver to the client:

```
$ tail -4 /var/log/apache2/access.log
192.168.111.101 - - [07/Jul/2016:20:41:06 -0700] "GET /about_smythies.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1515 "http://www.smythies.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
192.168.111.101 - - [07/Jul/2016:20:41:57 -0700] "GET /about_smythies.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1515 "http://www.smythies.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
192.168.111.101 - - [07/Jul/2016:19:52:55 -0700] "GET /bot_trap.html HTTP/1.1" 200 17542 "http://www.smythies.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
192.168.111.101 - - [07/Jul/2016:20:43:04 -0700] "GET /about_smythies.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1515 "http://www.smythies.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
```

Comment: Shouldn't they some how correct these anomalies? I mean, should it not at least look to see if the date/time before it is really before it?